# Why is pasted text highlighted in macOS Catalina's Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, copy-paste, macos-catalina

On macOS Catalina, when I copy text and paste to Terminal, the text is highlighted (basically, there are ANSI color codes enclosing the text). I don't know when this feature was included, but is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of macOS Catalina, the default shell for new accounts is now `zsh` instead of `bash`.

`zsh` has a feature called "bracketed paste" that allows the shell, specifically the zsh's line-editing mode known as "zle", to handle pasted text differently than if the same text had been typed in one character at a time, assuming your terminal emulator supports it, which macOS's built-in Terminal.app does. It's this "zsh line editing bracketed paste" that's highlighting your text.

To disable this feature, unset the "zle_bracketed_paste" environment variable:

```
% unset zle_bracketed_paste
```

You should be able to add that command to an appropriate shell startup script so that it's invoked every time (putting it in `~/.zlogin` worked for me).

Or you could switch your shell to bash if that's what you'd prefer:

```
% chsh -s /bin/bash
```

If you'd like to learn more about zsh's line editing mode's support for bracketed paste, see the `zshzle` and `zshparam` man pages.

Catalina's built-in version of `bash` is pretty old and doesn't support bracketed-paste, but the latest versions of `bash` *do*, so if you've installed, and are running, a version of `bash` recent enough to support bracketed-paste, you can disable it with the command `bind "set enable-bracketed-paste off"`. You can add that bind command to the appropriate bash shell startup file for your situation, or you can add just the `set enable-bracketed-paste off` part of it to your `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: I have bash from homebrew already `$ echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/bash`. `$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.` Does bash also add color code when copying? Or it is due to something else?

Comment: Yes, the version of bash you installed with Homebrew has its own form of bracketed-paste support. You can disable it with the command `bind "set enable-bracketed-paste off"`. You can add that bind command to the appropriate bash shell startup file for your situation, or you can add just the "set…" part of it to your `~/.inputrc`.