# Disabling bracketed paste mode in Anaconda-Python REPL on Mac

Tags: command-line, python, anaconda, tcsh

There is one thing I can no longer do on my Mac: Type a bunch of Python in my text editor, launch the Python environment from the command line, and paste a few quick commands into the interpreter. Bracketed paste mode pastes the multi-line block as some kind of highlighted single line:

[image]

It doesn't just run, I have to hit enter to send the highlighted text to the interpreter. When I do that, Python doesn't like it:

[image]

The weird thing is that this doesn't happen on the command line itself, only in the Python environment. It happens whether I start Python in the Mac Terminal, or XQuartz xterm.

I think the issue is bracketed-paste-mode. I found some tips on disabling it in [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611134/bash-bracketed-paste-is-it-supported) or [zsh](https://superuser.com/questions/1622933/why-is-pasted-text-highlighted-in-macos-catalinas-terminal), but have not found anything for csh/tcsh. [`printf '\e\[?2004l'`](https://jdhao.github.io/2021/02/01/bracketed_paste_mode/) or the more standard `printf '\033\[?2004l'` do not work for me.

The terminal command line itself is not in bracketed-paste-mode. When I launch Python, the Python environment is in bracketed-paste-mode. When I leave the environment, the shell again is not in bracketed-paste-mode. So somehow this mode is triggered only in the Python environment... and I cannot do `printf` escape codes in this environment.

Comment: `\e` is nonstandard; `\033` is standard.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey - Thanks for the suggestion. This also does not work. I added more info at the end of the question to explain.

Comment: Actually the place to look is not in csh/tcsh, but Python, e.g., [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/68193).  Looks as if it came from readline (e.g., the library developed with bash), and may be configurable in `.inputrc`.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey - This worked !! And I learned the vocab word REPL. If you want to write your comment up as a quick answer, I will gratefully accept it. Specifically, I did `echo "set enable-bracketed-paste off" >> ~/.inputrc` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`\e`** is nonstandard; **`\033`** is standard.

The place to look is not in csh/tcsh, but *Python*, e.g., [*Pasting into Python REPL broken in recent brew Python builds*](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/68193) (HomeBrew #68193).

According to a comment by [Carlo Cabrera](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/68193#issuecomment-753628592), the issue arose from readline 8.1 (e.g., the library developed with bash), who in turn referred to [rlwrap prompt disappears w/ readline 8.1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2020-12/msg00002.html) message by Felix C. Stegerman.  The suggested workaround is to configure the behavior in `.inputrc`, e.g.,

```
echo "set enable-bracketed-paste off" >> ~/.inputrc
```

Carlo Cabrera mentioned a blog which discusses the topic.  There is a more comprehensive viewpoint in the xterm FAQ: [*Can bracketed-paste solve my problems?*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_paste_nl), expanded in [*XTerm – bracketed-paste*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm-paste64.html)